# Restore the encrypted files contents from the Gallery Vault app

Tags: gallery-vault

I have reset my device and forgot to open the [Gallery Vault](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.galleryvault&hl=en) app, but I still have my encrypted files while unable to open them.

How can I restore the contents of the encrypted files?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the FAQ available at [ThinkYeah website](http://www.thinkyeah.com), they state that the encrypted files are stored in the folder `.thinkyeah/galleryvault` located on the SD card.

Further more, they state that if you install the application again and use your previous password you are able to retrieve all of your secured files.

## Relevant FAQ Entries:

- [Where are the encrypted files?](http://www.thinkyeah.com/myfaq/index.php?action=artikel&cat=2&id=8&artlang=en)
- [If Gallery Vault was uninstalled, can I find my photos and vedios back?](http://www.thinkyeah.com/myfaq/index.php?action=artikel&cat=2&id=9&artlang=en)

---

Since the encrypted files are located on the SDCard, **and assuming that the encryption key/file is located on that location or within the vault file itself**, you are able to recover your files installing the application and using your old password. Since you already mentioned that you still have the "vault" file, all appears to be in order, go ahead and try.

Answer (score 0):

Gallery Vault uses encryption to hide media. If you have done a Factory Reset, then there is no way to recover your previous data, even if the file still "exists". To decrypt, you would need some sort of decryption key or file, and chances are you lost it when you did a Factory Reset.